# Unable to Calibrate touch screen properly

Tags: touchscreen

I picked up an old Touch Screen Jukebox running on Windows XP. The touch screen works fine on windows so I know its not the screen itself that is faulty. I have Installed xinput_calibrator and it detects the touch screen fine and allows me to run the calibration tool, pressing all 4 markers but on completion, the screen is not properly calibrated. It detects me touching the screen but if i touch anywhere on the top left quarter of the screen, it detects the click in the very top left (0,0) and if i touch anywhere on the top right quarter of the screen it detects the clicks in the very top right corner of the screen etc...
I have installed xserver-xorg-input-evdev and switched to using this using the conf files but it is still the same! Has anyone else had a similar issue that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome! Please specify what OS you are using so we'll have a better understanding of this problem.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, its Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Thanks!

Comment: I have also managed to find out that the touch screen device shows up in Ubuntu as a "3m usb touchscreen - ex II"

Comment: I have ended up trying so many things I am going to cut my losses and reset it to a clean Ubuntu Install. Really not sure what to try next though really.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to obtain drivers for Linux from here:
https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/touch-systems-us/resources/3m-touch-drivers-and-kernel-patches/

I followed the instructions on the page to install it, rebooted it and it just works! It even has its own calibration tool